# Thread Timer returns NULL output

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that runs while a condition is false. For each second it is false, then it will add 1 second to the time, then return that time. My problem is that at the end of the code, it returns no output, that is, no integer variable is returned to output.

Note: For this program, assume that the user correctly guesses the number, and win is true.

Edit: Code execute() has been added to the while win = false

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
  public int run(boolean win){
     int time = 0;
     while(win == false) {
        try {
              time++;
              Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return time;
  }
}; 

public void execute() {
    thread.start();
}
```

This thread continues to increase while win is false, then returns the value of time when win is true.

```
 public void userGuessNumber() {
     boolean win = false
     [...] // Options Menu Code - timer should not increment for this section       
     while(win == false) {
      execute();
        if(guess == number) {
            win = true;
        }
 [...] // Do some code 
 }
}
```

Win is true when user guesses a number correctly. That is when the thread should stop incrementing. Then below is when the method outputs the time:

```
public void outputInfo() {
 System.out.print("The time it had taken to guess the number: ");
     execute();
}
```

Edited Code: I have added execute() in the while loop; my logic is that I want the thread to begin counting only when the user starts guessing a number. The execute() statement in the outputInfo method, I intend to print the number generated from time when the thread was running, but I believe this could be semantically incorrect.

execute is a method that runs the thread code, but for some reason the output it empty, and returns nothing.

Instead, I want it to return the number of the time that has elapsed before win reached true.

Comment: Firstly, why is execute() being called after the user gets the answer right? Also, the reason that execute() is not returning anything is because its return type is void. Even if it wasn't void, you don't print the "returned" integer either way.

Comment: When do you modify win in the scope of run()? Also, run() never gets called because you didn't actually override it, you overloaded it.

Comment: Do you really need a thread to do this? Why not just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: @java is life The reason execute() is being called is to start the thread. I only want it to start incrementing once the user is asked to guess a number. What I didn't mention is that I have other code before it, which is an options menu, that I don't want the timer to increment during. So, I executed execute() during the while false = true code, so that it would only increase the time when the user is attempting to guess a number.

Comment: The `win` updated in `userGuessNumber` is not the `win` passed to `run(boolean win)`, which is never called (in the code you show). Moreover, even if `run(boolean win)` were called, it would never complete, as `win` is passed by value and never changes. You could use a `Boolean` to get round that, but better is to give your `Thread`-class a member `boolean win` and a method to set it from the guessing thread. Then `run` loses its argument and overrides `Thread.run`, so it does get run. You also need to `join` your timer thread and retrieve the time from it. But @David is right: why a thread?

Comment: 'No output' is not the same as 'NULL output'; your thread is pointless; your variable scopes and the rules of Java make what you're attempting impossible; the JRE already provides not one but two methods to do exactly what you're trying to accomplish: futile question.

Comment: @PJTraill I am not aware of an easier way of accomplishing such task. I tried System.currentTimeMillis() but it caused the same issue; no output. Also, I don't think this would work since I only want it to begin counting during the while win = false; and my interpretation is that currentTimeMillis could possibly count from the beginning of the program's execution, which is not what I intend.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing output from a function (in the sense of the return value) with output on `System.out`. Almost no library routines – thank goodness – will write to `System.out`; you have to do that yourself. You need to call `currentTimeMillis` twice and take the difference. This is more reliable than seeing how often you can call `sleep` — that thread may spend some time blocked, which you will overlook.

Comment: Calling `execute` all over the place sounds like another disaster; I don’t know the semantics, but I would have expected it to throw an exception the second time, because `thread` is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't the proper use of a thread. Multithreading should be used for event handling or having long background processes such as a download.

You can easily just track the time by using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, assigning it to a variable and you'll be able to get the difference of time in milliseconds. If you want it in seconds, just divide by 1000.

Here's a snippet:

```
 public void userGuessNumber() {
     boolean win = false
     [...] // Options Menu Code - timer should not increment for this section       
     long guessNumberStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
     int timeElapsed = 0;
     while (!win) {
        if (guess == number) {
            win = true;
            timeElapsed = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - guessNumberStarted) / 1000;
        }
     }
 [...] // Do some code 
 }
```

Not only is the code shortened, you don't have any unneeded code running in the background, and you can calculate the amount of time that passed with more accuracy, given that you make the variable a double or a long.